# change content of multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to be able to change the content inside two divs when a button is pressed. When the player name is selected, one div needs to update their bio, and the next div their picture. At the moment once the button is selected it loads the same content into both divs.

```
<section id="container">
    <div id="playerMenu">
        <nav>
            <h3>Select a Player</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="adnan"  >Adnan Januzaj</a></li>
                    <li><a href="movie-2">Movie 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="movie-3">Movie 3</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>


    <article class="playerPic">
        <section id="picture">
                <div id="adnan1">
                        <img src="images/januzaj.png"/> 
                </div>  
    </article>


        <div class="playerBio">
            <section id="content">
                <div id="adnan">
                    <p>      Bio about Adnan Januzaj Here</p>
                </div>
        </div>

            </section>
        </section>
</section>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#playerMenu ul li a').click(function(){
                $('#content').load('players.html #' +   $(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            });

            $('#playerMenu ul li a').click(function(){
                $('#picture').load('players.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I am calling the information and pictures from a separate html file called players.html

```
<div id="adnan">
<h2>Adnan Januzaj</h2>
<p>Bio about Adnan Januzaj Here</p>


<div id="adnan1">
<img  src="images/januzaj.png"/>
</div>
</div>


 <div id="movie-2">
<h2>Phil Jones</h2>
    <img  src="images/jones.jpg"/>
<p>Bio about Phil Jones Here.</p>
 </div>
```

Is this possible to do? I understand how to change the content of one div, however by selecting one button is it possible to alter the content of 2 divs? Can one navigation button contain multiple href's?

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend looking into a MVVM like knockout.js, angular.js, or backbone.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot to add the 1 after the href tag in your javascript.

**javascript**

```
$('#playerMenu ul li a').click(function(){

    $('#content').load('players.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
    $('#picture').load('players.html #' + $(this).attr('href') + '1'); /* added the 1 */

    return false;
  });
```

I'd give your divs more clear ID's, such as "adnan-bio" and "adnan-pic" and append these to each href when you call load.

Answer (score 2):

You can put both changes in the same event listener:

```
 $('#playerMenu ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#content').load('players.html #' +   $(this).attr('href'));
    $('#picture').load('players.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));

    return false;
  });
```

Comment: @user3389460 Don't forget to accept, you get two rep!